# set_difference for a custom structure

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am trying to find the difference between the following two sets:

```
A = {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (2,2)}

B = {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
```

The answer I am expecting is

```
A - B = {(2,2)}
```

I tried the following code. But I am stuck unable to compile. Can anyone point out the mistake I am making?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class compare
{
  public:
    bool operator()(const pair <int, int> elem1, const pair <int, int> elem2)
    {
      return ((elem1.first == elem2.first) && 
          (elem1.second == elem2.second));
    }
};

int main()
{
  vector < pair<int, int> > v, va, vb;
  va.push_back(make_pair(0,0));
  va.push_back(make_pair(0,1));
  va.push_back(make_pair(1,0));
  va.push_back(make_pair(1,1));
  va.push_back(make_pair(2,2));

  vb.push_back(make_pair(0,0));
  vb.push_back(make_pair(0,1));
  vb.push_back(make_pair(1,0));
  vb.push_back(make_pair(1,1));


  vector < pair<int, int> >::iterator it, result;
  result = set_difference (va.begin(), va.end(),
      vb.begin(), vb.end(), 
      inserter(v, v.end()), 
      compare());

  // for (it = v.begin( ) ; it != result; it++)
  //   cout << "(" << it->first << it->second << ")" << ", ";
  // cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
The compile error message is the following:

```
set_difference.cc: In function `int main()':
set_difference.cc:36: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'result = std::set_difference [with _InputIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, _InputIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, _OutputIterator = std::insert_iterator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, _Compare = compare]((&va)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >](), (&va)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >](), (&vb)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >](), (&vb)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >](), std::inserter [with _Container = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >](((std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >&)(&v)), (&v)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >]()), (compare(), compare()))'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:587: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >&)
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: FFS. Computer, activate psychic hat.

Comment: Even if you get this to compile, You Will Have Problems.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added the compile errors.

Comment: @Kerrek can you suggest a better method of doing this?

Comment: You mean "a correct method"? I had one written up as an answer originally, but then saw that your actual problem was a compiling one, not a functionality one. I can undelete that if you like (and won't downvote it) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now with the error message posted it's clear what is the problem:
`set_difference` returns the output iterator, which in this case is an `insert_iterator` (constructed by your call to `inserter`). You try to assign it to `result` which is a vector iterator. This is a type mismatch.

The simplest solution would be to just omit that assignment and the iterator `result` because you don't need that iterator anyway; the results have been written to `v`.

Comment: Removing the assignment to `result` meant it compiled. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

(This is addressing the *correctness* of the algorithms, not the compilation problems.)

Read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/): The two input ranges *already have to be sorted*.

You also have to provide an *output iterator* for the result.

So do this:

```
std::sort(va.begin(), va.end(), compare());
std::sort(vb.begin(), vb.end(), compare());

set_difference(va.begin(), va.end(), vb.begin(), vb.end(),
               std::back_inserter(v), compare());
```

Your `compare` function should also define a **strict, weak ordering**, not an equality comparison.

By the way, `std::pair<S, T>` and `std::tuple<T...>` already come with built-in lexicographic comparison, so you shouldn't usually need to define your own comparison, unless you want something exotic: `std::sort(va.begin(), va.end());` etc.

Comment: `inserter` constructs an output iterator.

Comment: @Kerrek Thanks for correcting the algorithm and for the helpful explanations. It is really unfortunate that I could not pick two answers.

Comment: @Anand: No worries :-) Enjoy the C++ iterators and algorithms!

Comment: I find this answer more worthy then the selected "best answer".

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong: A - B is the set of elements in A not also found in B, which in your case is the empty set because every element in A is also found in B. B - A would give the result you expect.

Comment: I believe OP wants (A - B) + (B - A). Or, in math terms, B\A U A\B.

Comment: That's known as symmetric difference. But `set_difference` provides the set difference, as the name already suggests. So if the OP expects it to give the symmetric difference, his expectations are still wrong.

Comment: Change `v` to `v_l` and do `set_difference(vb, va, inserter(v_r))` for the right side. Then `v = v_l + v_r`. It will still produce unintended results unless the predicate `for (size_t i = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); ++i) v[i] <= v[i + 1]` holds for both va and vb.

Comment: No need to use another container. Since the inserter will just add to the existing container, reusing it for the second difference will automatically give the union (note that A-B and B-A are disjunct, therefore you don't have to worry about duplicates; however the result will not be sorted, so you might have to sort them afterwards if a sorted result is needed or desired).